# How do I integrate $2\phi_xs_x + s\phi_{xx} = 0$ to obtain $s^2\phi_x = I$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How do I Integrate $2\phi_xs_x + s\phi_{xx} = 0$ to obtain $s^2\phi_x = I$,
where I is a constant.

I have tried working back from $s^2\phi_x = I$, but when I differentiate this I obtain  $2\phi_xs_x + s^2\phi_{xx} = 0$.

Just wondering where my error is working backwards, as I cannot see a way to do this.

Many thanks.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: You are making a mistake when you differentiate the product, the derivative of $s^2$ is $2ss_x$ not $2s_x$

Comment: Ah yes, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(s^2\phi_x)_x=2ss_x\phi_x+s^2\phi_{xx}=s(2\phi_xs_x+s\phi_{xx})=0$, $s^2\phi_x$ is constant.